# calling bash script function with multiple options

Tags: bash, getopts

After calling a script `bash xyz.bash -ews`, only `e` is called, rest is being ignored.
My while loop with cases looks like that:

```
while getopts ":h:wrb:ep:s:" option; do
    case $option in
        h) echo "Help"
        Help;;
        w) ...
        ...
    esac
done
```

`wrb` belong to the first "class" of options, `ep` to the second and `s` is an option that needs an variable passed while calling a script. `h` echo's a help function but it works just fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I just put `echo $option` in the loop body and it showed all 3 options.

Comment: Why does `-h` require an argument?

Comment: @Barmar oh I thought the colon after `h` , `wrb` and `ep` indicates that these belong to different "class" of the options.

Comment: Where did you get that idea? There are no option classes. `:` after a letter means that it requires an argument.

Comment: Ok so that was my bad, I've just seen somewhere that colon was used to "seperate" the options or that was just my misunderstanding.

Comment: This might help: `help getopts`